How to remove value labels from radar chart created by ggradar in R?
Borrowing example code for creating a radar chart from r-charts.com, if I did not want any tick mark labels on my radar chart, how would I remove the "100%", "50%", and "0%" labels from the radar chart created by the example code?
set.seed(4)
df <- data.frame(matrix(runif(30), ncol = 10))
df[, 1] <- paste0("G", 1:3)
colnames(df) <- c("Group", paste("Var", 1:9))

library(ggradar)

ggradar(df)



ggradar(df, grid.label.size = 0). See the ggradar documentation for more details.
